# Approach to find contiguous region within logical time series

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a convenient and elegant existing approach to find contiguous regions in logical time series containing values True or 1?
I am looking for something returning ts summary of the form:

```
Region_id               Start                Stop
        1 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
        2 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
        ... etc
```

Example input ts:

```
mins <- function (N, from = as.character(Sys.time()), cols = 1, by = 1) 
{
deltas <- seq(from = 0, by = 60 * by, length.out = N)
nacol <- matrix(data = NA, ncol = cols, nrow = N)
xts(x = nacol, order.by = strptime(from, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + 
    deltas)
}

d <- mins(N=20,cols=1)
d[,1] <- F; d[5:12,1] <- T; d[14:20,1] <- T
d
                     [,1]
2012-12-18 20:48:00 FALSE
2012-12-18 20:49:00 FALSE
2012-12-18 20:50:00 FALSE
2012-12-18 20:51:00 FALSE
2012-12-18 20:52:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:53:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:54:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:55:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:56:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:57:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:58:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 20:59:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:00:00 FALSE
2012-12-18 21:01:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:02:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:03:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:04:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:05:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:06:00  TRUE
2012-12-18 21:07:00  TRUE

# so far for the _idealized_ input, now the function I am looking for to return data.frame 
# like this for the d object as above:
Region_id               Start                Stop
        1 2012-12-18 20:52:00 2012-12-18 20:59:00
        2 2012-12-18 21:01:00 2012-12-18 21:07:00
```

That is probably common task for binary signal processing so it is worth of searching. Of course, it is idealized. Just for start. The reality will be more complex.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? ...and don't let @joran edit it out of your question this time. ;-)

Comment: +1 for joran related comment

Comment: + another! take a look at `lubridate` and `as.period`... but thats all I got until I understand what a logical time series is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `rle` to find the contiguous blocks, then create an indicator to separate each block.

```
r <- rle(coredata(d)[,1])
ind <- rep(seq_along(r$lengths), r$lengths)
```

Now you can use the indicator to split your xts object, and run a min/max function on each contiguous block.

```
s <- split(index(d), ind)
l <- lapply(s, function(x) data.frame(start=min(x), stop=max(x)))
```

Then you can `rbind` the above result into one data.frame, create the `region` column, subset only the `TRUE` values, and take the cumulative sum.  Note that my times are different due to timezone differences, but the concept is correct.

```
out <- do.call(rbind, l)
out$region <- r$values
out <- out[out$region,]
out$region <- cumsum(out$region)
out
#                 start                stop region
# 2 2012-12-18 20:45:00 2012-12-18 20:52:00      1
# 4 2012-12-18 20:54:00 2012-12-18 21:00:00      2
```

Comment: So rle. Pretty easy, looking inside the function. This is interesting concept, I will follow it. Thank you.